# Alternate of nginx server

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, web-hosting

Currently I am using aws ec2 instance to host my backend and frontend . Backend is in nodeJs and frontend is in angular. ALso using route 53 for routing . and bought domain from goDaddy.

I have used following steps for hosting.

for backend :

1. clone my backend files on ec2 instance.
2. run backend nodejs program using pm2(used to run nodejs in background)
3. used nginx as reverse proxy to point localhost to my sub domain.

for frontend:

1. cloned frontend production files on ec2 instance.
2. used nginx to point frontend file to my main domain.

Now nginx is little bit complex to handle for me. Is there any way to avoid nginx or to host though any other way ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can host your (static) front end files on s3 and use cloudfront to deliver them

Comment: @danimal My frontend is not static. Its dynamic.

Comment: You can still do it, I will write up an answer

Answer (score 1):

If your frontend app uses angular, then presumably it's a 'Single Page App' that is only dynamic in the sense that it makes some kind HTTP calls to an (RESTful?) API provided by your nodeJS application.

If this is the case, then you can host the built version of the angular app in a public S3 bucket configured as a 'static' site, which will still be able to communicate with your backend via angular's `HttpClient`. You can use Route53 to point your bought domain at the bucket's `index.html` file, and also set up a CloudFront distribution if desired.

Your nodeJS app will continue to live on the EC2 instance, although you could consider either using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy the backend app for you, or at least setting up yourself a load-balancer and autoscaling group to give you fault tolerance and availability for the backend.